# Is there a way to attach file in sendmail command without using uuencode

Tags: shell-script, rhel, package-management, sendmail

I'm trying to send an email from shell script using the below code:

```
fileToAttach=cpu_usage.log

`(echo "To: XXXXXX@gmail.com"
  echo "From: XXXXXX@gmail.com"
  echo "Subject: Issue with CPU"
  echo  Issue with CPU
  uuencode $fileToAttach $fileToAttach
  )| eval /usr/sbin/sendmail -t `;
```

but I'm getting

```
uuencode: command not found
```

Is there any way to bypass it?

Comment: **ALSO** Do not forget about empty line to separate email headers from email body.  It is missing in your sample script.

Comment: Notice that, as stated in the respective man pages: `Uuencode and uudecode are used to transmit binary files over transmission mediums that do not support other than simple ASCII data.`. Is `cpu_usage.log` a binary file? If not it does not make sense calling `uuencode`.

Comment: What is the content of `cpu_usage.log`? Is it just text?, html?

Comment: just text. for example: 2020-02-26 11:52 CPU: 13.4%

Comment: if it's just a simple file, what can I use instead of `uuencode`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Red Hat the `uuencode` and `uudecode` commands comes with `sharutils` package.

On Red Hat Enterprise Linux 4, install this package by using up2date command.

```
up2date sharutils
```

On Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5, Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6, & Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 install this package by using yum command.

```
yum install sharutils
```

Source: [Which rpm package provides "uuencode" and "uudecode"command?](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/48627).

EDIT:

If the purpose is to send an email with a text/plain attachment file my suggestion is issuing the following commands:

```
fileToAttach=cpu_usage.log

(printf "To: XXXXXX@gmail.com\n"
 printf "From: XXXXXX@gmail.com\n"
 printf "MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
 printf "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"US-ASCII\"\n"
 printf "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n"
 printf "Subject: Issue with CPU\n\n"
 printf "echo  Issue with CPU\n"
 cat "$fileToAttach" 
 )| /usr/sbin/sendmail -t
```

As mentioned in [@AnFi](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/34195/anfi) commentary this solution supplies an empty line to separate email headers from email body.

Comment: Tnx, I will try it. is there any other way?

Comment: @arielma See my updated answer.

Comment: @arielma there are other encodings (check MIME documentation). At least the mh suite of commands (really a full mail reader/writer suite of tools) contain tools to compose/unpack messages/files with several pieces using MIME.